# An internal error has occurred in the secLdap plugin. null

Tags: java, crystal-reports, business-objects

We are not able to connect BO server (SAP REPORT).

Java Code.

```
String USER = "xxxxxxxxxx";
String PASSWORD="yyyyyyy";
String SERVER="zzzzzz:6400";
ISessionMgr sessionMgr = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession;
enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(USER, PASSWORD ,SERVER, "secLDAP");
```

we are getting below error

```
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException$SecurityError: An internal error has occurred in the secLdap plugin.
cause:java.lang.NullPointerException
detail:An internal error has occurred in the secLdap plugin. null
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.authentication.ldap.internal.LDAPError.ThrowException(LDAPError.java:69)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.authentication.ldap.internal.LDAPAuthentication.setClientParasSeq(LDAPAuthentication.java:119)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.PlugInLoader.setParams(PlugInLoader.java:189)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doLogon(LogonService.java:318)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:693)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.userLogon(LogonService.java:295)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.SecurityMgr.userLogon(SecurityMgr.java:166)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon(SessionMgr.java:425)
    at com.reporting.util.ReportManager.generateTokenBO(ReportManager.java:161)
    at com.reporting.util.ReportManager.main(ReportManager.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crystaldecisions.celib.misc.StringPatternHelper.split(StringPatternHelper.java:43)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.authentication.ldap.internal.LDAPHostInfoHelper.findHostElement(LDAPHostInfoHelper.java:132)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.authentication.ldap.internal.LDAPHostInfoHelper.findBestMatch(LDAPHostInfoHelper.java:110)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.authentication.ldap.internal.LDAPAuthentication.ExtractParameters(LDAPAuthentication.java:258)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.authentication.ldap.internal.LDAPAuthentication.setClientParasSeq(LDAPAuthentication.java:113)
    ... 8 more
```

kindly help to resolve this issue

Comment: 3rd parameter of logon should be a String. `SERVER:6400` is not a String, this code can't even compile. Please post the real code.

Comment: Code updated As per our policy we are not able to say server details.

Comment: This is a very generic error, you should run a trace to pinpoint where exactly on which line it is throwing this error and then adjust your code on that part.

Comment: enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(USER, PASSWORD ,SERVER, "secLDAP"); this line we are  getting error

Answer (score 0):

I even had the exact issue when migrating from 3.x to 4.2, There are some changes  to the Dependent Jar files of BI4.X.

The solution that worked for me is that, I have replaced my old BI jars with the new one and Added Few more jars jcmFIPS.jar,Tracelog.jar, jcm.jar.

These set of jar files can be found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP Business Objects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\lib".

I added the required jar files by finding the missing classes from my server error.

For more details --> https://help.sap.com/viewer/0225aa3e7b4b4b17b2d4a882e6f2de96/4.2.4/en-US/45f4d9ba6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html